# JS Turn button into whole page

Tags: javascript, html

i have button in a different color than the background and i want to turn the button into the whole page, but after that it shouldn't be clickable anymore, so after the click the button slowly turns into the whole page with the color spreading all over the page, i really hope i explained it correct.

I did a research on google about that, but couldn't find any matching results.

Also I'm new to JS, so please don't be upset if I don't know or don't understand any comments/answers.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you want is quite an advanced idea and it would not be done by actually turning the button into the page itself, but as an illusion.

If you want to animate something slowly, then I recommend looking into the [css transition property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition).

Comment: So you mean, i make the button with a transition bigger, and then when it covers the whole page, change the page with the same background? If so then thanks, i didn't think of that, if not thanks as well because you brought me on that idea :D

Comment: Something to that effect yes, when you make the button grow in size - at some point the whole page should change and the button should not exist on the page anymore.

Comment: maybe an element that has a background image of previous version of the page, on click start a fetch for the page content, slowly make the element take the whole page, and your fetch can `.then` the element from an img to the actual page